# Google app engine - Accessing datastore

Tags: javascript

Hi i wonder if you could help provide some advice;

I have a python script allows users to post messages to the google app engine datastore - which uses ajax to post a message to the app engine. What i am trying to achieve is to have - in javascript-  check the latest message being posted.
I have looked at the GQL docs but cannot find out how to check for the latest post.

```
// if {{message.**LastPost**}} == "hello"
//do this....
//end if
```

Answer (score 0):

The GQL query would simply be to order your data by the date ascending and then limit to 1.

*Example:*

```
SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY date_submitted DESC LIMIT 1
```

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference for reference.

If all you want is the latest record of your messages object which contains the DB query you can simply use something like `messages.get().message`

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.
I have put this into my python code:    
checkmessage = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Message ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 1")

Comment: how would i use this variable in the html/javascript thought? 

would i need to outut the checkmessage in python to json then use the {{ }} nottation in html/javascript checkmessage ?

Comment: tbh I was able to sort the messages. . My main issue here is trying to get the message to appear in the {{message}}

Comment: Yes you could do that, you basically just have to pack that object into the response message and access it with the {} notation.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'pack', how would i do that ? Just the same way i got the messages to output ?

Comment: Yes the same way. To be able to help at a code level I would need to see what you are doing and what templating system you are using i.e. Django, Jinja2...

Comment: if i do that i would have the same message variable in two response message

Comment: which throws a 500 error when deploying it to google app engine

Comment: here is my code here
i have added the sort to the JSON handler

http://pastebin.com/W2G7Y6sM

Comment: Byron I tried ust having 1 output and the message does not work with the {{message}} Could you tell me what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: I got this error when i tried the {{messages.get().message}}

File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/template/__init__.py", line 315, in invalid_block_tag
    raise self.error( token, "Invalid block tag: '%s'" % command)
TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag: 'messages.get().message'

Comment: TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: ().message